# UX research time! March 2019 and the user profile and settings

Tags: discussion, profile-page, user-experience, research, ux-research-time

‍♀️Hello! My name is Donna and I’m a UX (User Experience) designer here at Stack Overflow. Recently, Jon Ericson suggested that we share UX research updates so that the **folks here can get more visibility into one of the inputs we use to make product decisions**. Inspired by Dr. Julia’s [bite-size data science updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5468471/julia-silge?tab=questions), the design and research team is trying this out to see if this is interesting for y’all and if so, what kind of content and cadence makes the most sense.

Before getting started, please note that the research I’m sharing is informing a project that is still in the information-gathering phase, so you may not see near-term application of these ideas. Also, while this post concerns both Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, I’m posting here on MSO since Stack Overflow products like Teams and Jobs are important considerations as well.

With that, let’s dive in!

### Goal and research questions

We recently conducted interdisciplinary research to better understand behaviors and expectations toward the user profile & settings for Jobs, Teams, and Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Q&A users. This research was motivated by observed usability problems, the high cost of iteration and maintenance due to burgeoning technical and design debt, and the fact that this part of the site doesn’t support the needs of our business products.

**Our goal for this research was to better understand user problems with the profile and settings, who they affect, and the magnitude of these issues.**

More specifically, our research explored the following questions:

1. How do different user types currently use and perceive the user profile and settings?
2. How do users identify, if at all, with the following statements:

   - I want to have one unified profile that supports all of my Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange identities.
   - I want to have unique profiles per Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange identity.
3. How do other sites approach the “multiple identities” issue? “Multiple identities” refers to the ability for a single person to create and maintain unique identities within a given product.

### Methods and target users

We gathered insights through a [Meta.SE survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings), UX teardowns of other sites, data analysis, and 1:1 interviews with people of varying levels of engagement with Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Teams, and/or Jobs. The target users of our research included:

[image: target users - an image indicating five groups: average Q&A user, expert Q&A user, Q&A moderator, Job seeker, and Teams user.]

In the context of this project, each user type is equally important and not mutually exclusive (for example, a user can be an average Q&A user and a job seeker).

Below are highlights from our research. Out of respect for people’s privacy, any quotes I’ve included here have been paraphrased.

### How do different user types currently perceive the profile and settings?

**There’s a disconnect between expert users and average Q&A users, Teams users, and job seekers about the usability and usefulness of the profile and settings**. While many expert users were comfortable with the profile and settings, other user types had difficulty learning new patterns and navigating extra features to do basic things like managing their email subscriptions.

We explored the latter insight further by analyzing how other sites approach profile and settings navigation. This helped us better understand the expectations of non-expert Q&A users.

[image: settings navigation - an image comparison of reddit and Stack Exchange profiles where reddit has only six navigation items and SE has over twenty]

Note that low usage does not necessarily equal a decision to make significant changes to the feature itself – quantitative data is only one of several inputs into product decision-making. More specifically, the metrics above don’t lead us to the opinion that the Hide Communities feature isn’t useful. Rather, they might help us determine if there’s a better design or placement for the small group of people who get value from this feature.

### How do users identify, if at all, with the following statements:

- I want to have one unified profile that supports all of my Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange identities.
- I want to have unique profiles per each Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange identity.

**People were generally attracted to the ease-of-use of a unified profile and settings**. However, some felt strongly about maintaining site-specific control over certain parts of their identities – particularly reputation and badges. For example, one user stated, “having many separate profiles is disjointed. They need to be combined into a unified view.” Another said, “having one rep system would undermine my trust a bit… I find that rep reflects expertise around a certain topic, so it’s only useful for people interested in that topic.” Still another pointed out, “I like having a different ‘about me’ on each site that I use, and I’m concerned that would go away if all the profiles were combined.”

We explored the above insight further by getting data about how many Q&A users currently maintain site-specific profile data such as the display name, avatar, and About Me. We found that of the 1.2 million accounts that have more than one profile across the network, about 4% have unique display names, 7% have unique avatars, and 4% have unique About Me’s.

### What can we learn from other sites handling multiple identities?

**There are many other sites that allow users to maintain multiple identities within a single account.** Reddit and Discord each have one account with a blend of global and local data.

Reddit has one account, profile, and settings, with unique “flair” per community. Flair serves as a personal identifier. The type of flair data differs by the subreddit -- the example below shows flair as structured data, while other subreddits have flair that is free text, images, or other types of data.

[image: reddit flair selection box]

Discord has one account, settings, and username, with unique “nicknames” per server.

[image: discord nicknames - an image of the Discord setting that allows users to choose a nickname on a specific server]

### Next steps

We’re now wrapping up the first phase of information gathering for this project. As I mentioned above, this research helped us identify problems with the user profile and settings, who they affect, and the magnitude of these issues. It also helps product teams make decisions about prioritization, requirements, and scope.

Thanks for reading! Was this post interesting or helpful for y’all? What kind of research insights are you most interested in seeing?

Comment: Happy to hear that you looked at Discord for comparison! I feel like they've come closest among popular services to hitting an effective tradeoff between ease-of-use and flexibility here.

Comment: Can I ask how y'all decided to focus on profiles? Seems like, of all the different discussions here on meta, that's like the one place that *doesn't* feature in complaints.

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas! We choose research projects based a variety of inputs, only one of which is Meta. For example, we get a lot of feedback through 1:1 research interviews, and the things we hear in those don't always align with feedback from Meta folks. This particular research was motivated by observed usability problems, the high cost of iteration and maintenance due to burgeoning technical and design debt, and the fact that this part of the site doesn’t support the needs of our business products.

Comment: @Donna I think the last part of the last sentence is all you really needed to say :)

Comment: @DanBron I could, but that wouldn’t be accurate :) Yes, business needs are an important factor, but they aren’t meaningful if the work isn’t driven by actual user needs. We chose this focus because it affects 3 groups (business, users, staff) in significant ways. It's important to us to strike that balance wherever we can, and to challenge any user-facing work that isn't solidly grounded in a user need.

Comment: I have some suggestions related to `User Profile` and Overall `UI Design`, 1. To make left navigation of user profile < 20 you can make the navigation have just main menus like: `Personal Information, Email Settings, Site Settings etc`. When user clicks on the menu he see the sub menu related to it. 2. For overall UI Deisgn I like the look of `medium.com and hashnode.com` which is easy to eyes while reading code , This points maybe helpful for future design plans

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a programmer and a non-American at that... but until this point I thought UX meant Unix. I suspect there might be more of them programmers around here too, somewhere.

Comment: @stom thanks for the suggestions! +1 about the Medium and Hashnode examples.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for pointing that out. It looks like someone has added clarification to the post :)

Comment: A groups option would be nice. Not one really about socialization, but more about getting notified when another member of your group asks or answers a question. For instance, I used Unity and Javascript mainly, so I would join a group of people who specialize in either one. I know there are chat rooms, but those don't really feel "groupy".

Comment: Likewise, if you could split exchanges (e.g. all the programming ones) into different groups, then you could have different profiles on those.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Were you able to see if the answer to "global identity" vs "local identity" changed depending on the community?  For example, overall I tend to prefer a global identity, but there are a few specific sites where I'd prefer to deviate from that because I don't want a public link between e.g. my SO identity and my Interpersonal or Workplace identity, especially if I'm trying to maintain some separation between personal and private life. The system as it is now forces you to make a separate account to do this, but then I have to maintain all my other site settings in two places.

Comment: The Hidden Communities feature kind of addresses this, but it's unclear how well it works, so the safer thing is often to make a separate account if you're going to e.g. ask a question about your current boss/co-workers.

Comment: hi @Troyen, thanks for sharing your feedback. We didn't specifically delve into how this answer differs per community. Our priority was to understand general community sentiment.